# get a variable tha has specified content from a function inside a class

Tags: php, mysql

I have this class

```
class user{
    public function getmsg(){
    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE usertype = 'admin'";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql3);
        while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $whoposted = $user_data['whoposted'];
            $dateposted = $user_data['dateposted'];
            $title = $user_data['title'];
            $content = $user_data['content'];
            $whoposted = $user_data['usertype'];
        }
    }

}
```

assume that the object "db" has been declared. and my way of getting into the getmsg function is

```
$user = new user();
$user->getmsg();
```

now I want to get the content of $dateposted, how can i do that?

any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: you can make a getter setter variable for dateposted and set it on getmsg(); then access it

Comment: So user may have multiple messages, do you want all of them to be returned ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: No, I just want only one.

Comment: @nbin: so sad, i dont have any clue how to do that. can you give me ideas or hints atleast?

Comment: At the end of the function return the value something as `return $dateposted ;` and you can get it as `$user = new user(); $date = $user->getmsg(); echo $date ;`

Comment: maybe ill just try different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), in particular:

> Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.

In other words, your variables `$whoposted` etc are destroyed when the `getmsg()` function exits.

Not to mention the fact that, within the function, their values are overwritten on each iteration of the loop.

You *probably* want to define [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) within your objects within which you store data.  However, it'd be a strange thing indeed for a `user` object to retrieve news articles associated with multiple users.  Perhaps a more sensible design would be to have a `usertype` object representing admin users; and from there instantiate (from the results of the database query) separate `news` objects to represent each article?

1. Define a class to represent your news articles:

   ```
   class NewsArticle {
     const FORMAT_DATETIME_MYSQL = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

     protected $author;
     protected $date;
     protected $title;
     protected $content;

     function __construct($arr) {
       $this->author  = $arr['whoposted']; // would probably actually pass this
                                           // to a getUser() function that returns
                                           // a User object

       $this->date    = DateTime::createFromFormat(
                          self::FORMAT_DATETIME_MYSQL,
                          $arr['dateposted']
                        );

       $this->title   = $arr['title'];
       $this->content = $arr['content'];
     }

     function getAuthor()  {return $this->author;}
     function getDate()    {return strftime('%c', $this->date->getTimestamp());}
     function getTitle()   {return $this->title;}
     function getContent() {return $this->content;}
   }
   ```
2. Define a class to represent your "usertypes":

   ```
   class UserType {
     const SQL_GET_NEWS = 'SELECT * FROM news WHERE usertype = ?';

     protected $type;

     function __construct($type) {
       $this->type = $type;
     }

     function getNewsArticles() {
       global $mysqli;
       if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($db, self::SQL_GET_NEWS)) {
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->type);
         $stmt->execute();
         $result = $stmt->get_result();

         $articles = array();
         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
           $articles[] = new NewsArticle($row);

         $stmt->close();
         return $articles;
       }

       return null;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Then you can do something like:

   ```
   $adminType = new UserType('admin');
   foreach ($adminType->getNewsArticles() as $article) {
     echo '<h2>', $article->getTitle(), '</h2>';
     echo '<p>By ', $article->getAuthor(), ' at ', $article->getDate(), '</p>';
     echo $article->getContent();
   }
   ```

All of that said, most of this is just reinventing the wheel to build a (very simple) custom [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).  There are plenty of PHP ORM solutions already out there, many of which are free and open-source.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, that you have to return the complete message array to access the wanted data like this (your class with some improvements):

```
class user
{
    private $msg = null;

    private function loadData(){
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE usertype = 'admin'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql3);
        $this->msg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
    public function getmsg()
    {
        if(null === $this->msg){
            $this->loadData();
        }

        return $this->msg;
    }

}

$user = new user();

// since PHP 5.4
echo $user->getmsg()['dateposted'];

// for older PHP versions you can use this

$msg = $user->getmsg();

echo $msg['dateposted'];
```

or you can use a message object. But the solution is, to save the data somewhere and/or return the full result.

Answer (score -1):

try this procedure

```
<?php
class user{
    public function getmsg($key){
        $result=array();

    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE usertype = 'admin'";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql3);
     $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


        return  $user_data[$key];
    }

}

$user=new user();

echo $user->getmsg('dateposted');
```

Comment: Buggy code.. correct it before you get flooded with down votes.

Comment: I got error 'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp\www\inventory\core\engine\class.engine.php on line 86'

Comment: before use this method you should connect to the database first